# Why is the Swiss Political Model not Replicated / Proposed Elsewhere?

Tags: comparative-politics, switzerland, direct-democracy

Switzerland is generally recognized as a quite functional and prosperous society. It also features a political model with quite unique features:

- All significant parties participate in the executive branch of the state (the federal council).
- There is frequent use of direct democracy by mean of referendums (multiple times per year on the most different matters).

Given that the system seems to be working quite well, I am surprised no other country adopted it or that this system is not proposed as an ideal model to be adopted by many political parties/associations.

Is that a particular reason?

EDIT:
As one of the answers points out, one other key element of the Swiss political system is strong federalism.

Comment: Frequently asked about:  https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/18549/21531 https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/9670/21531 are two I can think of.  Which found by a [search on the direct-democracy tag and Switzerland](https://politics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdirect-democracy%5D+switzerland)

Comment: Switzerland is a small, geographically isolated and landlocked, highly wealthy country that is ethnically homogenous. I'm reasonably certain that *any* political system (or none) would work just fine for them.

Comment: @Valorum _is_ Switzerland ethnically homogenous, though?  It has four official languages and more immigration than many seem to think.

Comment: @phoog - https://media-cldnry.s-nbcnews.com/image/upload/t_fit-1240w,f_auto,q_auto:best/streams/2012/April/120429/343789-pb-120429-townvote-cannon.jpg / https://www.nautilusint.org/globalassets/news-by-topic/switzerland/swiss_womens_strike_basel_theaterplatz_news.jpg. Various flavours of 'white European' does not equal "ethnically diverse" in my opinion :-)

Comment: @Valorum what does then?  Do not confuse skin color with ethnicity.  Some years ago I moved from one neighborhood in New York that had many different varieties of white European immigrants to another that was primarily a mix of white and black American nonimmigrants.  A few of my friends saw the larger number of dark faces on the street and said "this neighborhood seems much more diverse."  It wasn't.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Direct democracy is only one of the key characteristic of the Swiss model. Discussing it isolated from the other elements might lead to a simplistic analysis.

Comment: @Valorum - Do different flavours of English speaking people make different identities more than different flavours of white skinned Europeans? I don't see Switzerland as ethnically and culturally less diverse than the United States, or than a Switzerland-sized patch of the United States. However, an important factor is that Switzerland is less politically polarised than other countries (at least after mid 19th century).

Comment: Another important fact, is that Switzerland uses proportional representation at all levels of government, including for the executive branch. The highest level of the executive branch is the Federal Council (7 members from 4 different parties), and the President's role is mostly ceremonial. This system allows votes for smaller parties to actually count (unlike in a winner-takes-all system), and leaves enough space for smaller parties to thrive.

In order to replicate that system, it would mean that whoever is already in power (or aspires to be) would have to relinquish some of it.

Comment: @Pere As a US citizen who has lived in Switzerland, I guarantee you that the ethnic and culture diversity of the United States is far greater than that of Switzerland. Just on the neighborhood block where I live in New Mexico there are White, African American, African (from Somalia if I remember correctly), Vietnamese, Latino, and Laotian families, each with their own cultural traditions and perspectives. While Switzerland is not as uniform as some assume (I met a handful of Sri Lankan immigrants when I lived there, for example), it isn't nearly as diverse as the US. Not even close.

Comment: @LordOfThePigs I think "whoever is already in power (or aspires to be) would have to relinquish some of it" is spot on and actually the tl;dr answer to this question. I suggest you post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some people claim that referendums may lead to "wrong" outcomes, citing Brexit as an example. I think this claim misses the point of the Swiss system. The Swiss system is not just about getting "correct" outcomes through referendums; the very fact that people may force a referendum fundamentally changes the political system.

In a standard democracy, people usually vote for a party that is closest to their highest-priority ideological stance. For example, if your highest priority is tax reduction, you will probably vote for a party that promises tax reduction. You will do so even if you do not like most or all of the party members. This opens the door for politicians who are corrupt, or just not very smart, to get into the parliament, only because they represent a certain ideology that many voters support.

In contrast, in the Swiss system, you can promote your highest-priority ideological stances through popular initiatives: you just have to find 100,000 citizens with the same ideology, and then sign a petition that forces the government to put this issue to a referendum. As a result, when you vote for the parliament, you do not have to vote according to your ideology alone. You can vote for people whom you consider smarter or more honest, knowing that the ideological issues can be handled outside the parliament.

This means that, if a country switches to the Swiss system, the composition of the parliament would change substantially, with many incumbent parliament members losing their jobs. This explains why so many parliament members oppose the Swiss system. They make up all kinds of excuses (e.g. "Brexit"), but at the end, they just want to keep their jobs.

APPENDIX: The following comment by Tim expresses a similar idea:

> I'd like to add, as a Swiss, that an enormous value of having referendums is the social peace it brings. Since everyone had a say in it, those unhappy with the decision are much less likely to violently express their anger, compared to when the decision is centralized (e.g., in a government).

Comment: Some people being me? Personally, I wonder at "some people" who always accuse all politicians of being on the take and that seems to be the crux of the argument here. It is a lazy argument and I see it as a major factor in political polarization as it facilitates the rise of "drain-the-swamp" demagogues because no one trusts politicians.  *Trust but verify* instead.

Comment: Very good point. By letting most ideological battle be settled by referendum, collaboration in administrative matters become easier.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica, the onus is on politicians to help us trust them; not on us to trust them blindly (which is exactly what we need to do due to how the system works in other countries than Switzerland). At least in my country (Germany) there is precious little going on that makes building trust very easy; and a lot in the opposite direction.

Comment: I'm not sure this is true. The main effect that is clearly observable with regards to parliamentary elections is that people care less. In Switzerland the participation in federal elections is much lower than in surrounding democracies. When some important and polarizing issue is on the ballot on the other hand, then it's not unusual to have high turnouts. For example the covid pandemic and measures against it polarized a lot, so when there was a referendum about the solutions proposed by the government there was 65% participation.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica not just you... I heard these arguments many times. And I do not claim that *all* politicians are corrupt. But their number is sufficiently large so that they can block any substantial change in the political system.

Comment: Apologies for being snippy.  In the interest of clarity:  my point was not so much to put down referendums or convince people not to use them.  Instead, I have grown more concerned over the years with the tendency people have to put down politicians, *as a whole*.  That breeds low expectations and tolerance for electing some people massively unsuited for that job, especially on repeat, as "they all suck anyway".  I assume your main point was a) about referendums, not b) accusing all politicians of corruption, but my comment was targeting b).

Comment: Other answers point to the example of the Republic of California which also has referendums. I agree it changed the political system, but I don't think it changed it in the way asserted in this answer.

Comment: I'm unconvinced that "social peace" or less violence are due consequences of frequent referenda. After Switzerland, Italy is a distant second; is it more politically peaceful than the rest of Western Europe? Bosnia and Herzegovina is also very decentralized: the three ethnic groups are guaranteed to have a say, and yet tensions have continued to grow.

Answer (score 38):

#### Don't forget extreme federalism, a key feature of the Swiss model

I would add at least one more key element of the Swiss model, which is that it is a federal system that pushes political authority for many policies to smaller political units than most countries, in part, in response to the fact that it is a multi-lingual country with differing mixes of languages between cantons (only 4 of 26 cantons have more than one official language).

The [twenty-six Swiss cantons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantons_of_Switzerland) have populations and geographic areas comparable to U.S. county governments, which are among the smallest units in a federal state anywhere in the world. As noted at the link:

> The areas of the cantons vary from 37 km2 (15 sq. mi.) (Basel-Stadt)
> to 7,105 km2 (2743 sq. mi.) (Grisons); the populations (as of 2018)
> range from 16,000 (Appenzell Innerrhoden) to 1.5 million (Zürich).

[image]

(via [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantons_of_Switzerland))

Yet, cantons have political power closer to U.S. states or Canadian provinces, than they do to U.S. local governments, and they each have local governments within them that also have significant political autonomy (Switzerland has 2,222 municipal governments, with an average of roughly 4,000 people each, with many municipal governments even within its largest urbanized areas). To achieve comparable levels of political decentralization, the U.S. would have to have about 3000 states.

> The Swiss Federal Constitution declares the cantons to be sovereign to
> the extent that their sovereignty is not limited by federal law. Areas
> specifically reserved to the Confederation are the armed forces,
> currency, the postal service, telecommunications, immigration into and
> emigration from the country, granting asylum, conducting foreign
> relations with sovereign states, civil and criminal law, weights and
> measures, and customs duties.
>
> Each canton has its own constitution, legislature, executive, police
> and courts. Similar to the Confederation, a directorial system of
> government is followed by the cantons.
>
> The cantonal legislatures are unicameral parliaments, with their size
> varying between 58 and 200 seats. . . .

So, even a canton with just 16,000 people has at least a 58 person legislature and also elected municipal officials and referenda providing additional means of democratic input. The only U.S. state with anything close to this many legislators per capita is New Hampshire.

> The cantons retain all powers and competencies not delegated to the
> Confederation by the federal constitution or law: most significantly
> the cantons are responsible for healthcare, welfare, law enforcement,
> public education, and retain the power of taxation. Each canton
> defines its official language(s). Cantons may conclude treaties not
> only with other cantons but also with foreign states (respectively
> Articles 48 and 56 of the Federal Constitution).
>
> The cantonal constitutions determine the internal organisation of the
> canton, including the degree of autonomy accorded to the
> municipalities, which varies but almost always includes the power to
> levy taxes and pass municipal laws; some municipalities have their own
> police forces.
>
> As at the federal level, all cantons provide for some form of direct
> democracy.

The vast majority of countries with its area and population have unitary national governments instead. Switzerland has the population of 8,670,300 (considerably less than Ohio, and with less land area, and less still habitable land area).

The involvement of all significant parties in the Federal Council, is possible, in part, because the central government is comparatively weak due to this strong federalism and due to the amount of political decision making that takes place through direct democracy.

The central government in Switzerland has power only comparable to what the central government in the U.S. did before the U.S. Civil War, which was not much. And it [doesn't have a small national legislature either](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2023_Swiss_federal_election), with a lower house of 200 legislators and an upper house called a "Council of States" with 46 legislators (two each in the twenty historical full cantons and one each in the six historical half-cantons). The U.S. has roughly twice as many legislators as Swiss national parliament does, but more than 38 times as many people.

Indeed, given the large number of elected legislators at the local, canton, and federal level in Switzerland, it is something of a surprise that it needs direct democracy too. But it does have that in spades:

[image]

#### Different elements of the Swiss model have been replicated.

Italy, for many decades after World War II, had the same set of five centrist parties in the government (which constantly saw coalitions break down and then reform) with a very broad political range, in order to political isolate the far left and far right, producing a similar effect but with much less stability, and has more direct democracy than any European countries other than Liechtenstein and Switzerland.

Bosnia, Iraq, and Lebanon all require that all major factions in their countries have representation in the top level decision making bodies.

The radical decentralization of Swiss cantons with an express model in Bosnia and a moderate influence of multiple post-Yugoslavian countries. [Bosnia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantons_of_the_Federation_of_Bosnia_and_Herzegovina) even calls its ten subdivisions cantons.

Many U.S. states make heavy use of direct democracy, even though the U.S. federal government does not, and the U.S. is also heavily decentralized although not quite as much as Switzerland. Many European countries have some direct democracy, largely as a result a result of the Swiss model, although not nearly as much as Switzerland and many U.S. states. A high level of direct democracy was also the norm historically in New England in town government.

[image]

#### The Swiss have one of the world's oldest democratic political cultures

A comment from NoDataDumpNoContribution notes:

> More direct democracy is proposed quite often here and Switzerland is
> also named as an model then, but then there is often the difference in
> population named as one reason to not follow through. Maybe what works
> with less than 10 million people doesn't anymore with more than 100
> million? Also the history of Switzerland is quite unique with the
> long-standing neutrality. Maybe Swiss people honed that way of
> creating consensus for a long time and one cannot easily copy it?

This too has a lot of merit to it. Switzerland is one of the oldest republics, in the narrow sense of not having a hereditary monarchy, that still survives as an independent country in Europe, so it has had a much longer time to build its political culture. Key elements of its system have been in place since the 13th century, before any Europeans other than a few Vikings had set foot in the New World (and they didn't last), and only a little after the Norman Conquest of England and democratic experiments in Iceland.

The organization of its military, relying heavily on conscription, also builds national unity and consensus in a way that might not otherwise have been possible. This in turn was possible, in part, due to Swiss international neutrality, which in part, was made possible by an Alpine geography that was not hospitable to invaders given the military technologies in place for most of its history.

The strong role of conscripts in the military forcing public involvement is matched by the large number of people per thousand who serve in some canton or municipal office, in addition to federal legislators, creating a large pool of politically savvy and experienced citizens.

And, while it is linguistically diverse (German is the only official language in 17 cantons, French is the only official language in 4 cantons, French and German are the official language in 3 cantons, Italian is the only official language in one canton, and Italian, German, and Romansh are the official language in one trilingual canton, Grisons, with 200,000 people and a sixth of the country's land area), it does not have the kind of political/cultural diversity and division seen within Northern Ireland or Belgium or the United States or pre-2014 Ukraine or Italy or even unified Germany, let alone non-Western countries like Lebanon, Iraq, Syria, Nigeria, Rwanda, Mexico, Indonesia, the Philippines or Thailand. Diversity within individual cantons where power is concentrated in this confederation is even smaller.

Switzerland may have more political/cultural diversity than Finland or South Korea or Japan or the Netherlands or Iceland, but it still only has so much.

Comment: Great answer!  But I question the final paragraphs about having less political/cultural diversity. There is a great deal of difference between Geneva and Appenzell, not unlike the difference between rural Wyoming and Boulder, Colorado.  There are cultural differences between the Swiss German-speakers and Latin speakers, there exists an animosity between Ticino and the north.  But they manage to settle their differences, because they share the most important identity: that they are NOT German, French, or Italian, even though someone from Lausanne is more likely to study in Paris than in Zürich.

Comment: I like the answer. The comparison with the Italian pentapartito decade seems a bit stretched since they it was not spanning the whole Italian political spectrum.

Comment: The map of the number of referendums per country seems suspect - fairly sure that the UK has had four just in my lifetime

Comment: @MikeB Has your lifetime been lived in Scotland? If so, you had an extra three referendums about devolution and independence. The UK as a whole has had only 3 (join EU, leave EU, not change to PR).

Comment: Scalability is a big factor. Some features of government models aren't nearly as scalable as others. And even if you take the exact same model and transplant it to a new country, it wont operate the same way. Culture influences a lot on how government operates. Even so, this answer does illustrate a lot of elements of the Swiss model that is replicated elsewhere. The two pointed features in the question are also two points heavily influenced by culture.

Comment: The GDP per capita also helps to smooth over some things that might be a source of division elsewhere.

Comment: @TAR86 Switzerland was a relatively poor country through most of democratic history and only became relatively wealthy in 20th century.

Comment: Switzerland cultural differences run deeper than you think. They have even different religions, and religion wars were going through Europe!

Comment: "political power closer to U.S. states or Canadian provinces": in many important respects they have more autonomy than both US states and Canadian provinces.  "Bosnia even calls its ten subdivisions cantons": confusingly, it is the Federation of Bosnia and Herzegovina (the roughly one half of Bosnia and Herzegovina, the other half being Republika Srpska or the Serb Republic) that has subdivisions called cantons.

Comment: @phoog Both good points.

Comment: @pinpon It is not obvious, at least to me, looking at the parties in the federal legislature, that Switzerland has political parties that are as far right and as far left as those of Italy during the Italian pentapartito decade, although I admit that this could conceivably be due to me not understanding the politics of some Swiss political parties. It appears the Italy and Switzerland spanned a similar range from the political center and both lacked the far right and far left extreme, which Italy has and Switzerland does not have. If I am incorrect, which Swiss parties are as extreme?

Comment: @ohwilleke comparing parties in between countries is difficult. The point is that in Switzerland the federal council span the whole parliamentary arc. The pentapartito was not. Many positions of the swiss people party can be probably considered far-right for italy (now and in the past). The counterexample would be an extreme swiss party with significant members in the national council (> 10%) that was excluded from the federal council.

Comment: @ohwilleke fantastic answer (upvoted). This does not change the content of this answer in the least, but I am unsure of the US map of direct democracy. I live in a state that's gray and we've had, "ballot initiatives," that look remarkably like referendums and often contain language specifying change to the constitution or statute. Am I missing some critical point?

Comment: @ohwilleke About Switzerland being less politically diverse than Italy and Germany in the 60s 70s, I tend to agree. I am not so sure this is till true post 89-now.

Comment: Not to mention that all these referendums and extreme federalism is expensive and time consuming to maintain. It means you have to be a fan of spending a lot of money on political infrastructure, and many countries, including other wealthy ones who could conceivably afford it, are not.

Comment: @pinpon What changed? What extreme right or extreme left parties are currently in the Federal Council?

Comment: @ohwilleke Italy changed not Switzerland. Italian Communist party dissolved and Movimento Sociale Italiano too. As for Switzerland some positions of Swiss People Party seems indeed far right.

Comment: To give my swiss perspective here as well, I think culture plays a big role in it too (together with the conscription). Contrary to most Americans I know, I almost never hear anyone here really discuss politics or politicians much; voting seems to just be a private matter. Nobody I know openly identifies with one specific political party the way Americans (and sometimes Germans) seem to do. The Kollegialitätsprinzip also plays a role to not have too many rowdy politicians (the last one that comes to mind was C. Blocher?). It just doesn't feel like politics are a dominant topic around here.

Comment: @Katai For readers who aren't familiar with it, the Kollegialitätsprinzip is a German language term usually translated as "the collegiality principle, also known as the collegial principle" and it describes a type of leadership of authorities and governments. The government or authority consists of equal elected representatives who represent the decisions made in secret voting to the outside world with one voice." https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kollegialit%C3%A4tsprinzip Westminster-style parliamentary systems usually have some version of this principle for cabinet members.

Comment: The recent ballot measure in Kansas on abortion rights is often called a referendum, so the map either doesn't reflect reality or it doesn't reflect common usage.

Answer (score 14):

##### TLDR:  This answer isn't saying referendums are always bad. Only that they are not always good, and no, there is not always a magic way to unwind bad ones before they do real harm. Like most complex systems, there are tradeoffs and knowing when and how  referendums can be used is key.

see also this [answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/18550/21531), on a linked question, about referendums.

And, concerning Swiss federalism, not really addressed here.  See [this other answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/86619/21531).

---

Are direct referendums always a good idea though?

Look at [Proposition 13 in California](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1978_California_Proposition_13#Effects), which has a lot of them and they don't always make sense in aggregate. Prop 13 reduced *taxes* - not always equitably either - but Californians also voted themselves a lot of *services and regulations*.

Or Switzerland's less than glorious introduction of women's votes in its last canton in 1990.  [Not by referendum, by the Supreme Court](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Women%27s_suffrage_in_Switzerland#Introduction_of_women%27s_suffrage_at_the_cantonal_level).

For that matter, the way the referendum system started in Switzerland itself is a bit of [an oddity](https://blog.nationalmuseum.ch/en/2021/11/the-first-popular-initiative/)...

The Swiss model *can* work, true.  Doesn't mean it will work everywhere and at any scale (there's probably a limit to how far down you want to refer each and every political decision to a referendum).

##### Speaking of referendums... Brexit.

Bottom line:  it mostly works [in Switzerland](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/86619/21531).  Doesn't mean it automatically is a great idea everywhere, for everything.

p.s. I asked a question about cannabis legalization and referendums and [the answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/77063/21531) also stated that a good case for referendums was on "morally sensitive issues". They can also get used for independence referendums, to ask the affected population if they want to secede or not.  I'd add that British Columbia has on two occasions that I am aware of, used a referendum to ask voters if they wanted to change the electoral system (ward-based councillors for the city of Vancouver, switch to proportional representation in the province's parliament).  They've also been used to ask about the [death penalty](https://ballotpedia.org/Death_penalty_on_the_ballot) in US states.

**These are particular types of questions, *that are less about day-to-day management than they are about what kind of society the voters want to live in*.**

They are not "routine" regulation initiatives Or "tax less" initiatives, potentially followed by - supposedly unrelated - "spend more" initiatives, which is what hasn't worked out all that well in California (Prop 13 backed by houseowners, [Prop 184](https://lao.ca.gov/analysis_1995/3strikes.html) - Three Strikes, You're Out, backed by the prison industrial complex).  Or the equally daft [proposition 65](https://oehha.ca.gov/proposition-65/about-proposition-65), triggering a brouhaha about [cancer warnings on Starbucks coffee](https://www.latimes.com/opinion/op-ed/la-oe-abrams-coffee-cancer-warning-20181011-story.html).

---

p.s. Thought I'd add something insightful from the comments:

> *I'd like to add, as a Swiss, that an enormous value of having referendums is the social peace it brings. Since everyone had a say in it, those unhappy with the decision are much less likely to violently express their anger, compared to when the decision is centralized (e.g., in a government).*

(Though that effect is probably more pronounced in a high-functioning referendum context - Switzerland - that a low-functioning referendum context - arguably, California)

Comment: Ref. to "there's probably a limit to how far down you want to refer each and every political decision to a referendum)" - I do not have time to search about this, but I think that political and financial education plays a very important level for this to work well. I guess, the higher the democracy level towards (letting folks decide on more and more things), the higher the education level needed for this not to go terribly wrong.

Comment: @Alexei Maybe less formal education than a certain level of political maturity, and perhaps accommodation, that the Swiss seem to have achieved but can be lacking elsewhere?

Comment: The women's voting right referendum is a hugely misleading mention since most Swiss cantons enacted the right for women to vote decades before that. Dragging that out means that you fundamentally missed the federal nature of the country.

Comment: @Mavrik Yes, as clearly indicated by **in its last *canton* in** in my answer ;-)   
 Here's a [*federal*, minaret, example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2009_Swiss_minaret_referendum) since you insist.  My answer *isn't* concerned with federal or not - California has no federal arrangement *in the state*.  It is cautioning that not all types of governance questions, with all electorates, work well through referendums.  Some types of decisions are better suited than others, some are worse.

Comment: Well, the minaret example is embarrassing, but it had pretty much zero consequences, otherwise it would have been reversed by now. Brexit is a good example I think: It's dangerdous in a country with one-off referendums without a solid legal ground. If the UK had the referendum/initiatives laws of Switzerland, 1) the remain camp would have won because a simple majority would not be enough for radical change and 2) if it had succeeded, there would have been at least another 1-2 votes on the matter with the potential to reverse the decision and/or compromise.

Comment: And the women's vote thing... yes, that's how the system is designed: new ideas, even really good ones, take a long time to be adopted, mitigating much of the dangers of direct democracy. On the plus side, even when some objectively stupid new law is passed now and again, usually this law is mitigated or even outright ignored because the government knows that if it actually implemented the law, it would just be repealed (after people feeling the consequences) and the people who fought for the stupid law complain loudly but live with it because they know they only won by chance.

Comment: The state prison population, along with the generous pay for wardens, were a frequent problem with balancing California budgets, IIRC - though I think that was walked back a bit last time there was a budget crisis.  Again, this answer is not saying referendums are always bad.  Only that they are not always good, and no, there is not always a magic way to unwind bad ones before they do real harm.  Like most systems, there are tradeoffs.

Comment: @Mavrik only four decades before that, though; the first canton granted women the right to vote only in 1959. More notorious in my estimation is the federal advent of women's suffrage in 1971.

Comment: @phoog 1959 is late, but not overtly so across europe or the world.

Comment: @Nobody *this law is mitigated or even outright ignored because the government knows that if it actually implemented the law*  Can you clarify what you mean here?  Brexit was, famously, a *non-binding* referendum.  But is that the case in Switzerland?  If *all* referendums are non-binding, then isn't that taxpayer $$$ waste?  And *if it implemented the law* seems a dangerous amount of leeway for a government to give itself.

Comment: Very interesting point about the not so glorious start of referendums in Switzerland. The women vote at federal level in 1971 was decided by a referendum so maybe is a good point for allowing them. I think the answers is too focused on referendums and do not consider other points of the Swiss political system.

Comment: Also, I think you are a bit cherry picking about the specific bad outcomes of some selected referendums. One could easily find a lot more stupid laws passed by parliaments. Or stupid decisions taken by elected government officials.

Comment: This answer define referendum's outcomes (good/bad) only based on the decision itself. I'd like to add, as a Swiss, that an enormous value of having referendums is the social peace it brings. Since everyone had a say in it, those unhappy with the decision are much less likely to violently express their anger, compared to when the decision is centralized (e.g., in a government).

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica All referendums in Switzerland are binding, but if they go strongly against what the majority of elected representatives wants, then they better be extremely specific, otherwise they will be ignored. That was the case with an anti-migrant measure that passed, but because it conflicted with some important very mutually beneficial agreements with the EU, it was implemented only in the letter of the law not the spirit or (if you ask its proponents) not implemented at all.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica It's an example of voters demanding something stupid without being sufficiently informed, but in order to pass the text had to be vague enough (otherwise enough moderate voters would have seen through the xenophobic agenda and voted against it) so that now the government can interpret it however it wants.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica It really is quite a lot of leeway for the government, and it would be fair to regard it as a bug, but it's also a feature sometimes. The effect generally is to add a lot of intertia to everything, no matter if the change would be good or bad. There is no chance in Switzerland for mob rule or something like that because political change happens so gradually that any fad would have faded by the 10 years it takes to take effect in law.

Comment: @Nobody Since you have so much to say, why not write an answer, as opposed to commenting on mine so much?  I ain't gonna change it all that much, besides noting on top that it is not ruling them out overmuch, only... "buyer beware".  Tim's remark about social peace is much more insightful, as well as being shorter.

Comment: I don't think I can answer the question. I work in Swiss politics and maybe I know enough about German politics to make a comparison, but I wouldn't dare generalize.

Comment: @Nobody Well, then please stop loading this up w endless comments, though you're welcome to downvote it if you feel like it.

Comment: (+1) Having lived in California for more than three decades and having been a voter for the past 17 years, I would claim that [California ballot proposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California_ballot_proposition) are more of a curse than a blessing. What works in Switzerland may not scale well to a population of 39M. Not infrequently even well-informed voters have trouble pinpointing what exactly they are voting on (std advice: "When in doubt, throw it out"). Too many of the props passed by voters have had unintended negative consequences, proposition 13 (1978) being just *one* example.